# AngularDart unit test with useShadowDom: false

Tags: unit-testing, dart, angular-dart

I am trying to write a unit test for an angular.dart (1.1.2) component that has useShadowDom set to false.  I don't seem to be able to find a way to reference the scope of the component like I can if useShadowDom is set to true.

```
@Component(
    selector: 'test_component',
    templateUrl: 'test_component.html',
    useShadowDom: false
)
class TestComponent {

    bool clicked = false;
    clickHandler() {
        clicked = true;
    }
}
```

And then in my test:

```
inject((TestBed tb) async {
        Scope s = tb.rootScope.createChild({"clicked" : false});
        Element el = tb.compile("<test_component></test_component>", scope: s);

        microLeap();
        await tb.rootScope.apply();

        ShadowRoot root = await el.shadowRoot;

        // When useShadowDom: true, then use root here instead
        Element theButton = el.querySelector("#the_button");
        theButton.click();

        microLeap();
        await testBed.rootScope.apply();

        // If I do this with useShadowRoot: true, then it works perfect 
        // (true) but root is null with useShadowDom: false and if I pass 
        // element, then scope.context is just a map with the original
        // values (clicked = false).
        print((testBed.getScope(root).context as TestComponent).clicked);

        // This just prints the original values (clicked = false)
        await s.context.forEach((String key, Object val) async => print("$key : $val"));

});
```

Update:
We found a work around for this, but it is not ideal.  The only way we could get a reference to the context was to recursively call getScope on all the elements in the tree until we find the right one.  This only works if the component has an attribute that ties it to the scope, so something like mustache syntax still doesn't work correctly.

```
dynamic getComponentContext(Node el, Function typeCallback, TestBed tb) {
    if(el is Element && el.childNodes != null && el.childNodes.isNotEmpty) {
        Scope s = tb.getScope(el);
        if(typeCallback(s.context)) {
            return s.context;
        }
        else {
            for(Node childNode in el.childNodes) {
                var c = getComponentContext(childNode, typeCallback, tb);
                if(c != null) {
                    return c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you just start with Angular.dart or is it a grown project where you want to introduce unit testing?

Comment: It is an existing project (approximately 9 months old) with existing unit tests.  We were adding new functionality along with the new unit tests but ran into this issue.  In this specific instance, the work around above gets us by... but this seems to be a bug in testbed.